# Why won't PySys_SetPath() work?

Tags: c++, python, c, api

I'm using the Python C API, and numerous times now I've tried using PySys_SetPath() to redirect the interpreter to a path where I've stored all of my scripts. Yet, every time I try it, I get the following error:

Unhandled exception at 0x1e028482 in app.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.

I use it in the following syntax: `PySys_SetPath("/Python/")`. Is that incorrect? Why does it keep crashing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using '/Python/' or "/Python/".  The type of quotes makes a difference in C.  '' is for a single character.  "" is for a string.

Comment: I'm using double quotes.. I just used single quotes above because my code was quoted in double quotes. Force habit. Bad practice. But yeah, double quotes.

Comment: Please don't do that. I've edited the question to use backticks, which show up as a fixed-width font.

Comment: Sorry.. so, any idea why it won't work?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your python directory is located in your systems root folder, the path is named wrong. It should be

```
PySys_SetPath("Python");
```

assuming that the python folder is located in the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but when I fixed all the `\` to `/` and added a `.` at the beginning of the path it worked 
 ie. the path should look sth like that `PySys_SetPath("./Python/")` or `PySys_SetPath("C:/full/path/Python/")`